# How to capture facebook page's like event in app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to capture javascript events on Facebook page iframe tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227504/how-to-capture-javascript-events-on-facebook-page-iframe-tabs)

I want to capture Like button click event for a facebook page in my facebook app.

e.g. http://www.facebook.com/teesort?ref=ts&sk=app_117117158324901 .

Here, when one clicks on like on top of the page, it redirects to new page where new offer is available.
I want to develop exactly same but I am not able to figure out how do I capture event of clicking on like button on the facebook page.

I have created Iframe based facebook app and I am using javascript sdk. I can capture the event of facebook like button present in my iframe. However, I can not capture click event  of default like button on facebook page.

I have used following code.

```
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
          alert('the user likes a page);
    });
```

I would appreciate any insights on this.

Kind Regards,
Amrish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227504/how-to-capture-javascript-events-on-facebook-page-iframe-tabs